# Expose Volume of Kubernetes to non-kubernetes apps

Tags: kubernetes, containers, persistent-volumes

I am new to Kubernetes and am working on a Computer Vision project, in which, some of the services are deployed in Kubernetes and some of the services are running in a cluster of physical servers (Nvidia Jetson Boards) which has GPU. Can the non-Kubernetes services access the Persistent Volume of the K8s environment? Please let me know,

1. How to expose a Persistent Volume from K8s and mount it as a shared drive in a different physical server?
2. Instead using Persistent Volume, can I have a volume in the host machine where K8s is deployed and can I use it for both k8s and non-k8s services?

Please note that we are connecting Cameras through USBs to each of those Jetson Boards, so we cannot bring those Jetson Boards as nodes under K8s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not possible.
2. This is a better approach. Example, you can use [NAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) to back the k8s and the nvidia board cluster, both clusters can share files thru the NAS mounted volume. For pods on k8s cluster to access the mount point is as simple as using `hostPath`, or a more sophisticated storage driver depends on your storage architecture.